# Is $x^4+4x-1$ irreducible in the field $Q[\sqrt{-7}]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

I already know this is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Right now, my general plan is to show there is no root in $\mathbb{Q\sqrt{-7}$ (thus no linear factor). And then show that two quadratic factors are impossible as well.

e,g To solve the first step, I thought about just plugging something like $a+b\sqrt{-7}$ with $a,b\in \mathbb{Q}$ into the formula to see if a root is possible but it does feel very very clunky.

Is there a better way to do this?

I am using the textbook Dummit and Foote and am working through section 14.6 on Galois Groups of Polynomials and this came up as part of solving one of the exercices (namely exercice #10, determine the Galois group of $x^4+4x-1$).

Comment: Traditionally, we stick to squarefree $d$ when talking about $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$; here, $-28 = -2^2\times 7$, so $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-28}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$.

Comment: Also: since this is degree $4$, even if you don't find a root, that would not establish that the polynomial is irreducible.

Comment: Ok, I edited my question to reflect the traditional way.

Comment: If it had a root, then it would have a root which is an algebraic integer; and since the constant term is a unit, the root would be an algebraic integer unit. But the units of the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$ are $1$ and $-1$ (e.g., use the Norm map), neither of which are roots, so the polynomial has no roots in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin That's a nice observation. Can you exclude quadratic factors in a similar way?

Comment: @Servaes: no (which is why I removed it from your answer). But it is a "better way" of verifying no linear factors, as the OP asked.

Comment: It's reducible in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2).$

Comment: As Michael Rozenberg observed, the quartic factors over $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$
$$x^4+4x-1=(x^2+1)^2-2(x-1)^2=(x^2-\sqrt2 x+\sqrt2+1)(x^2+\sqrt2 x-\sqrt2+1).$$ I let Mathematica simply solve the roots, and their simple form gives this immediately. I have not checked whether the usual algorithm for figuring out the Galois group works, but surely it is a 2-group, so either $D_4$ or $C_4$.

Comment: Using the factorization from my comment above it is easy to write $\sqrt{-7}$ in terms of the zeros and $\sqrt2$. Therefore the splitting field contains at least two distinct quadratic fields, and we can conclude that the Galois group is the dihedral group $D_4$ of symmetries of a square.

Comment: Oops. Scratch the last comment. I forgot about the transitive copy of Klein four inside $S_4$ that is also an alternative that needs to be excluded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** My original answer was wrong; the polynomial *is* reducible over $\Bbb{F}_9$. In fact
$$x^4+4x-1=(x^2+\beta^2x+\beta)(x^2+\beta^6x+\beta^3),$$
where $\beta\in\Bbb{F}_9$ satisfies $\beta^2+\beta-1=0$. I leave my original answer here for future reference:

If the polynomial is reducible over $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$ then it is also reducible over its ring of integers, which is $\Bbb{Z}[\alpha]$ with $\alpha:=\tfrac12(1+\sqrt{-7})$. Then reducing mod $(3)\subset\Bbb{Z}[\alpha]$, which is prime in $\Bbb{Z}[\alpha]$, yields
$$x^4+4x-1=\overline{f}\,\overline{\vphantom{f}g}\quad\text{ in }\ \Bbb{F}_9[x].$$
Of course it is not hard to factor this polynomial over $\Bbb{F}_9$, and a quick check shows that it is irreducible [**Edit: It is not!**]. It follows that the given polynomial is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. It seems to me that $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]/3\mathbb{Z}[\alpha] \cong \mathbb{F}_{9}$, so you would need to check that $X^{4}+X-1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_{9}$. Have I misunderstood your argument?

Comment: @AlexWertheim You have not misunderstood; you are right. I'll try to fix it up tomorrow, it is clearly too late for me now.

Comment: Why is it enough to consider the polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_9$ and deduce the irreducibility over $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$?

Comment: @Diger This shows that either $\overline{f}$ or $\overline{g}$ is quartic, and hence either $f$ or $g$ is quartic if $x^4+4x-1=fg$, which means that it is irreducible.

Comment: Do you mind showing how you would factor it over $\mathbb{F}_9$?

Comment: @Diger I made a mistake in checking irreducibility last night; it turns out the polynomial *is* reducible.

Comment: Why are you using $\alpha=\frac{1+\sqrt{-7}}{2}$ for $\mathbb{F}_9$ and not $\sqrt{-7}$?

Comment: @Diger The ring of integers of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$ is $\Bbb{Z}[\alpha]$, not $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}]$, and then I obtain $\Bbb{F}_9$ as a quotient of $\Bbb{Z}[\alpha]$. In this context it is natural to think of $\Bbb{F}_9$ as $\Bbb{F}_3[\alpha]$, and easier. It is of course isomorphic to $\Bbb{F}_3[\sqrt{-7}]$.

Comment: Sorry again. I'm also wondering if I use $\beta=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$ and plug it in the product at the top, expand and take mod 3 I then arrive at $$x^4 + 4x + \beta^4 \, .$$ Can $\beta^4$ be reduced to $-1$?

Comment: @Diger No problem. In $\Bbb{F}_9$ you have
$$\beta^4=(-\beta^2)^2=(\beta-1)^2=\tfrac14(\sqrt{5}-3)^2\equiv-1.$$

Comment: Not sure..That is what I got too, but isn't $\mathbb{F}_9$ with respect to mod 3?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92106/discussion-between-diger-and-servaes).

Comment: +1 for coming up with an idea that might have worked. But, if a quartic $\in\Bbb{Z}[x]$ were to remain irreducible over $\Bbb{F}_{p^2}$ its roots would then  have to generate $\Bbb{F}_{p^8}$, and this is surely impossible, no?

Comment: Why is $\beta \in \Bbb{F}_9$ if $\Bbb{F}_9$ is $\Bbb{Z}[\alpha]/3\Bbb{Z}$, I mean isn't there a $\sqrt{5}$ and not $\sqrt{-7}$ ?

Comment: @Diger in $\Bbb{F}_9$ we have $5\equiv2\equiv-7$.

Comment: @Jyrki You are absolutely right, it was a silly idea (but a nice exercise for myself nonetheless).

Comment: @Jyrki: Why is that so that if a polynomial remains irreducible over $\Bbb{F}_{p^2}$ then the roots would generate $\Bbb{F}_{p^8}$?

Comment: @Diger If you adjoin a root of an irreducible quartic to a field, you get a degree four extension. The one and only degree four extension of $\Bbb{F}_{p^2}$ is $\Bbb{F}_{p^8}$.

Comment: ... and those zeros cannot be in $\Bbb{F}_{p^4}$ because that is a quadratic extension of $\Bbb{F}_{p^2}$ only. The scene would be markedly different if we were dealing with a cubic. The zeros of a cubic, irreducible over $\Bbb{F}_{p^2}$, clearly belong to $\Bbb{F}_{p^6}$. But, in that case there is no reason why they might not actually belong to the subfield $\Bbb{F}_{p^3}$. The somewhat coincidental fact that $2=[\Bbb{F}_{p^2}:\Bbb{F}_p]$ is a factor of $4=\deg x^4+4x-1$ is relevant.

Comment: This is probably not the best place to ask, but I don't know where and I don't want to open a new question for these seemingly simple questions as a newbie to the field. Is it possible to write private?
**1.** You say the roots of the quartic would have to be generated by $\Bbb{F}_{p^8}$, but this is surely impossible, but on the other hand the roots of a cubic clearly belong to $\Bbb{F}_{p^6}$. Why is it impossible on the one hand but not in the other case?

Comment: **2.** Just to be clear. If the roots of the quartic $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_4$ generate $\Bbb{F}_{p^8}$ then every $x \in \Bbb{F}_{p^8}$ can be expressed as $a_1\alpha_1 + ... + a_4\alpha_4$ where $a_1,...,a_4 \in \Bbb{F}_{p^2}$?